# DI: Composition root decomposition

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, inversion-of-control, code-injection

[Composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) looks very strange pattern. We have a single very large God object that knows everything about anything.

What's the correct way to split up a Composition Root to some modules that will encapsulate initialization of its own part of the object graph?

What about [hierarchical dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)?

Comment: "What the correct way to split up composition root". That might depend on the technology you are using. You are refering to Angular documentation. Is your question about DI in the context of Angular?

Comment: @Steven, I need conceptual answer. You can provide samples from any technology, if it will help you to explain.

Comment: Here is a related article: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1285/clean-composition-roots-dependency-injection

Answer (score 11):

I don't agree with the premise that a Composition Root is a [God Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). While, conceptually, a Composition Root may contain many lines of code, it has only a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): compose an object graph.

A Composition Root can contain much data, and itself be coupled to the entire application, but it'd conceptually have only *one* method. It has only one reason to change, and that is if you want to change the way your application is composed.

Also, while the Composition Root is coupled to the rest of the application, the application code knows nothing of the Composition Root. Thus, the coupling goes in only one direction, as it should, according to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

A way to put it is that a God object violates all five [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), while a Composition Root at the very least follows both SRP, ISP, and DIP. I don't think the [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) or [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) apply here.

All that said, if a Composition Root composes a big application, it could still contain much code. If you find that it becomes unmanageable, then how should you break it down into smaller chunks of code?

The same way you decompose any other code. It Depends™.

I hope I never wrote or said that a Composition Root can only be a singe class. If I did, I'd like to retract that. When writing Composition Roots, I routinely split its responsibilities over more than a single class (although rarely more than a handful). You can apply any design pattern or other OOD technique you'd like in order to achieve that goal. The Composition Root then becomes a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) over your implementation.

I can't give much more guidance than that, because it depends on the application architecture. If you do vertical slicing, you'd most likely need to structure the Composition Root differently than if you do horizontal layering, and so on.

That said, as a general rule I *do not* find it useful to attempt to decompose a dependency graph into sub-trees. First of all because a dependency graph is a *graph*, and not a tree, but also because you often need to interleave multiple independent concerns. You could, for example, have sub-graphs that are responsible for various sub-parts of your application, but then you'd need to interleave the same logging mechanism, or the same caching mechanism, or the same security mechanism, etc. throughout the entire graph. You can't easily do that if you try to separate them.

Comment: Thanks you. Composition Root has a lot of reasons to change - every class, listed in it is a reason. And its changes very often. The problem with decomposition is quite dificult and lead to invetion of whole new patterns. Look at the Matt's answer - he introduces couple of new concepts - factories, stock strategy, broker interface... Is it Composition Root yet? Or look at Angular implementation. The problem needs to be thinked out to prevent appearance of new anti-patterns I think.

Comment: "Composition Root has a lot of reasons to change - every class, listed in it is a reason." - This is only true if you are explicitly calling the constructor of every class (which may change) in your composition root rather than wiring up the individual classes by themselves and letting the container put them together. Or better yet, register most of your classes by convention so you have very little composition code at all and then finding a way to organize it isn't such a big concern.

Comment: @NightOwl888 even if you use DI container, adding, removing, renaming and moving classes will raise change of composition root. By the way, automatic instantiation by DI container may cause not obvious errors, such as use of not registered service (wich will be discovered only runtime). So, using DI container also makes composition root less managable.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I still would like to hear your opinion on Composition Roots for a server-side application. The problem I encountered is that for each request, some stateful objects will be created (and form a graph) while the application-wise objects remain stateless, but it becomes complicated to build this per-request graph without a composition root. Is it ok to have a per-request composition root? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: The particular problem we encountered is like this. We have a class A and a class B that is both stateful and both depend on class C which is also stateful. For each RPC request we want to construct one A, one B and one C where A&B depends on the same C instance, forming a runtime object graph. But if we compose our application with three factories AFact->CFact and BFact->CFact and call AFact and BFact to construct A and B, we will end up with 2 different C instances. Should we implement a per-request composition root that build this runtime graph?

Comment: @JasonZang I never meant to imply that the Composition Root code can only *execute* once. It can definitely build object graphs per request. See e.g. https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/03/compile-time-lifetime-matching for an example.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Although since I'm one of the few C++ DI enthusiastic weirdos perhaps I need to adapt your example with some templating and `constexpr if`, or separate `create` into multiple functions, your example perfectly solved our problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pavel I solve the "missed dependency" issue with a unit test that iterates all registered services and attempts to instantiate them. This opens a whole can of worms sometimes, but is the only effective solution I've found when using DI containers like Autofac. It takes  a while to get it "right", but after that I have personally found it adds a lot of value.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the community is not in total agreement on how the Composition Root should look like.

For example, you can wire up your objects manually by practicing [Pure Dependency Injection (Pure DI)](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), or you can use a Dependency Injection Container and register your mappings manually, or you can use a Dependency Injection Container and create some conventions around class and interface names to achieve what is called Convention over Configuration. Or maybe you can mix between these three approaches.

Another example: you can choose to wire everything inside the Composition Root (the better option in my opinion), or you can choose to have a "small Composition Root" for each component (e.g. a class library in .NET) in the system, and then wire these roots in the "main Composition Root".

Depending on which approach you choose, the knowledge of the Composition Root will vary.

For example, if you use Pure DI and have a single Composition Root, then the Composition Root will need to know very much about the application.

On the other hand, if you follow the Convention over Configuration approach, then some of the knowledge about which classes should be mapped to which interfaces will be distributed all over the place (inside class and interface names, etc.).

Based on my experience, Pure DI + having a single Composition root is the best option for any application that is large enough. This gives you a central place to understand the application, and makes your [Composition Root navigable](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1285/clean-composition-roots-dependency-injection).

This means that the Composition Root has a very big responsibility. I am not sure if we can call it a God object. I think that the context where this term was coined is different.

I wouldn't say that the Composition Root does "too" much. Although it does alot, I think it is supposed to. If you are like me, then you want a single location where you can navigate and understand your application.

To decompose your Composition Root, you can split it into multiple methods. I sometimes create a partial class in C# (a single class in multiple files) and put related methods into the same file.

Although the application graph is a graph, it will be much easier to decompose if it was a tree. I try my best to make the graph tree-like. If two objects require a similar dependency, I try to give them different instances of such dependency to maintain the tree-like structure of the graph.

I have written an article about this topic, you can read it [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1285/clean-composition-roots-dependency-injection).

[Here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1259/liskov-substitution-principle-perspective) is also another article that provides some perspective on the responsibility of the Composition Root.

Comment: Thanks, you listed all obvious things, but do not touch core of the problem. If we split composition root, then some depenencies will be common, some specific to modules (or tree of modules?). Main question is how to organise interaction between common and specific parts, make it predictable, maintable and easy to manage.

Comment: @Pavel, the only things that need to be shared are shared stateful objects and shared resources (e.g. open and locked files). For these objects, you create them at the last possible location, and then pass them as parameters in the Composition Root methods. All other stateless objects do not need to be shared. I explain this in detail in the "Code sharing versus Resource/state sharing" section of the [linked article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1285/clean-composition-roots-dependency-injection).

Comment: @Pavel, by the way, it makes a lot of sense to maximize the number of stateless "objects" and minimize the number of stateful "objects". This will help you a lot with maintaining your Composition Root (among other things). Here is a related article: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1367/data-encapsulation-large-csharp-applications

Comment: Its good idea, but looks like it is from ideal world. Do you have an expirence of using this in real big applications?

Comment: @Pavel, yes. The articles I write are based on my experience building large applications that are in maintenance for years.

Answer (score 1):

The composition root isn't really a God object, because it only knows about the *unencapsulated* parts of the object graph.

In the component hierarchy, the composition root has some number of children, and the object graph that it creates materializes the interdependencies between these children.  A trading portal might be configured with a stock strategy, a mutual fund strategy, and a broker interface.  The strategies require a broker interface and the portal UI requires one or more strategies.  The composition root connects them together.

Now, any of these injected dependencies -- the trading strategies or broker interface, could have a lot of *internal* functionality that can also be configured by dependency injection, but the composition root should not have any hard-coded knowledge about those internals.  Instead, the composition root can be configured with *factory* implementations to build the complex dependencies.

The factory implementations may require resources from the composition root.  The trading strategy factories will both need the broker interface implementation, for example.  But they all require the *same* things from the composition root, so that the composition root doesn't need to know about their specifics.

If necessary, the resources passed through to the factories can include DI configurations for the factories that are opaque to the composition root. The factories can thereby create whatever object graph is appropriate to implement the object they are supposed to create.

It is important to note that the factory interface -- the thing that the application calls to construct the object it needs -- is specific to the *application*.  It is the *same* across all of the configurable ways to satisfy a particular type of dependency.  There will be a `TradingStrategyFactory` interface above, for example, with different implementations for mutual funds (using the mutual fund module) and stocks (using the stock module).

Unless the factory interface is standardized in some way, then, the factory interface and implementations are **part of the application, NOT part of the modules that implement the functionality they use.**

Occasionally, requirements will change and some new module will require a resource or connection that isn't provided by the composition root. This will require a change to the factory interface and all the implementations of it.  It should *NOT* require changes to other modules, and so these factory implementations are properly part of the application itself.

So, finally...   The answer to your question is that a large and complex composition root decomposes into multiple factory implementations of various kinds.

You also mention hierarchical DI in Angular.  This is a mechanism for automatically passing configured resources through to component factories.  I'm not familiar with Angular, but I would guess that it's required because Angular tries to standardize a single factory interface for all components.  This has the effect of moving construction of the object graph itself into the DI configuration in a hard-to-understand way.  You don't need this if you're programming in .net, and I would avoid it in that environment.

Comment: Thanks, but can you provide some links to read about this technique of depcomposition to factories? Its dificult to understand whole picture from your text.

Comment: Sorry, no links.  This answer comes from experience, not book learnin'.  I'll think about what might be hard to understand in it, though.  Meanwhile the @steven you've hooked above is co-author of the book you reference, so maybe you'll get a golden answer from him.